# How to get last date along with its multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id    date1         date2
101  2021-10-01    2021-09-01
101  2021-11-01    2021-10-01
101  2021-11-01    2021-12-01
102  2022-09-01    2022-09-01
102  2022-11-01    2023-01-01
103  2021-10-01    2021-11-01
103  2021-10-01    2021-11-01
103  2021-12-01    2021-11-01
103  2021-12-01    2021-12-01
103  2021-12-01    2022-01-01"""), sep="\s+", parse_dates=["date1", "date2"])
```

I am trying to get the latest `date1` for each `id` along with its multiple entries. My expected result is as below

```
id    date1         date2
101  2021-11-01    2021-10-01
101  2021-11-01    2021-12-01
102  2022-11-01    2023-01-01
103  2021-12-01    2021-11-01
103  2021-12-01    2021-12-01
103  2021-12-01    2022-01-01
```

In this case `drop_duplicates` with `keep='last'` will only give me the last entry for each id but I need all last dates in each id. And `groupby` with `tail` will not work because the value for `tail` is not static and can differ for each id. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: OP by last, do you mean the last chronologically, or in the dataframe? They seem like they are the same thing in the example, but they might not be the same thing in reality

Comment: what I mean is, say there is a group that goes, `['25/12/2022', '15/3/1990'] - the last one chronologically would be the one in 2022, but the last one in the group is the one in 1990

Comment: @Mark I understand your question. The last date is chronological and yes the data should be sorted or it is already sorted in my dataframe.

Comment: @mockash. If you want the most recent date, you don't need to sort the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby_transform` and check if the current date is the most recent date for each group:

```
>>> df[df.groupby('id')['date1'].transform(lambda x: x.max() == x)]
    id       date1       date2
1  101  2021-11-01  2021-10-01
2  101  2021-11-01  2021-12-01
4  102  2022-11-01  2023-01-01
7  103  2021-12-01  2021-11-01
8  103  2021-12-01  2021-12-01
9  103  2021-12-01  2022-01-01
```

**Note**: if you want the last date value (last row) for each group and not the most recent date, you can replace `x.max() == x` by `x.iloc[-1] == x` (assuming your dataframe is correctly sorted else use `df.sort_values('date1')`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
# for the last date, chronologically
df[df.groupby('id')['date1'].transform('max').eq(df['date1'])]

# for the date of the last row
df[df.groupby('id')['date1'].transform('last').eq(df['date1'])]
```

Comment: Clearly better than my answer! More efficient

Comment: @Corralien I prefer your answer :P my answer is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, filter the max date(latest date) rows per group,

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g[g['date1'] == g['date1'].max()]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**Output:**

```
    id  date1       date2
0   101 2021-11-01  2021-10-01
1   101 2021-11-01  2021-12-01
2   102 2022-11-01  2023-01-01
3   103 2021-12-01  2021-11-01
4   103 2021-12-01  2021-12-01
5   103 2021-12-01  2022-01-01
```